# How to make Powershell script run in all sub directories?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008

I've been able to piece together this script to remove periods from the file names without affecting the extension.  I've been struggling to make it run in the subdirectories without manually running it in each one.

This is the script I've been using:

```
dir | rename-item -newname {       
       [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.name).Replace("."," ") + 
       [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.name); }
```

Best,

Connor

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Basename.replace("."," ") + $_.Extension }
```

That's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

try using something like `dir -recurse`

Answer (score 0):

You can do recursive search(search subfolders) using the `-Recurse` switch for `dir / Get-ChildItem`.

I would also suggest using powershell properties instead of `[System.IO.Path]` functions:

```
$_.BaseName     #Filename without extension
$_.Extension    #File-extension
```